# How adding providers on IIS windows Authentication C#

Tags: c#, iis, kerberos, windows-authentication, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm working on IIS (Version 8.5) on Windows Server 2012 R2.
I try to active Kerberos authentication with C#, adding the Negotiate provider and putting usingAppPoolCredentials = True.
When I test my code on other devices (Windows 10, IIS 10.0 / Windows Server 2016, IIS 10.0) it's ok.
According to the Microsoft docs, there is no difference between IIS 8.5 and IIS 10.0 for adding providers.
I found a web.config file on my Windows Server 2012, maybe this file blocks the change.. So how can I delete this file or cancel its generation by IIS ?

Have you got any solution or idea ?

Thank you

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var iisManager = new ServerManager();
            var sites = iisManager.Sites;
            var site = sites.CreateElement();

            site = sites.Cast<Site>().ToList().Where(siteTmp => siteTmp.Name.Contains("Default")).First();

            var siteName = site.Name;
            Configuration config = iisManager.GetApplicationHostConfiguration();
            ConfigurationSection windowsAuthenticationSection = config.GetSection("system.webServer/security/authentication/windowsAuthentication", siteName);
            var providers = windowsAuthenticationSection.GetCollection("providers");

            providers.Clear();


            var ntlm = providers.CreateElement("add");
                ntlm["value"] = "NTLM";
            providers.AddAt(0, ntlm);

            var negotiate = providers.CreateElement("add");
            negotiate["value"] = "Negotiate";
            providers.AddAt(0, negotiate);

            providers = windowsAuthenticationSection.GetCollection("providers");

            windowsAuthenticationSection.SetAttributeValue("useAppPoolCredentials", true);

            iisManager.CommitChanges();
        }
    }
```

The web.config file generated by IIS when I edit by hand :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <authentication>
                <windowsAuthentication>
                    <providers>
                        <clear />
                        <add value="NTLM" />
                    </providers>
                </windowsAuthentication>
            </authentication>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: `iisManager.CommitChanges();` is going to commit the changes to whatever files it decides to be proper (either `applicationHost.config` or `web.config`), so get used to that please. The choice is determined by many factors, such as configuration section's mode.

Comment: could you please share what the web.config file contains?

Comment: @LexLi how can I choose the modified file ?

Comment: @JalpaPanchal here is my web.config file